# EERROR! conflicting action statements: user, update_password

Tags: ansible, yaml, devops

I decided to write a simple script, but something went wrong, I hope for your help.

```
---
- name: Reset root password, disable users
  hosts: all
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  vars:
    vault_ansible_production_root_password: 123456
  tasks:
    - name: Reset root password
      user:
        name: root
        password: "{{vault_ansible_production_root_password}}"
      update_password: always
    - name: Disable user accounts
      user:
        name: "*"
        state: absent
        uid: ">=1000"
        remove: yes
```

ERROR! conflicting action statements: user, update_password

The error appears to be in '/etc/an_script/work.yml': line 8, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

tasks:
- name: Reset root password
^ here
PS

I'm just starting, please don't throw too many tomatoes )))

[Ran through debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vL1By.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indentation's wrong.

With your current code, "user" and "update_password" are at the same level: Ansible doesn't know which one is the plugin to call: conflicting statement

Try this instead:

```
tasks:
- name: Reset root password
  user:
    name: root
    password: "{{vault_ansible_production_root_password}}"
    update_password: always
```

See docs, params of that module should be one level down: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/user_module.html